# Ruby lacks constant expressions optimization?

Tags: ruby, optimization, benchmarking

I'd expect Ruby's parser would make this trivial optimization, however is seems it does not (speaking about YARV implementations, Ruby 1.9.x, 2.0.0):

```
require 'benchmark'

def fib1
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 9999**4000
        a, b = b, a+b
    end
    puts "\tdone !"
end

MAX_FIB = 9999**4000
def fib2
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < MAX_FIB
        a, b = b, a+b
    end
    puts "\tdone !"
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    Benchmark.bm do |r|
        r.report('plain') { fib1 }
        r.report('predefined constant') { fib2 }
    end
end

plain    done !
 32.810000   0.220000  33.030000 ( 33.069854)
predefined constant    done !
  0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.119303)
```

As both methods are identical except use of predefined constant instead of an constant expression in the second, it seems Ruby interpreter calculates power constant each loop again and again.

Is there some material why Ruby does not do this basic optimization at all or just in some specific cases ?

Comment: Even if it *were* possible, this *certainly* wouldn't be done in the parser but in the optimizer.

Comment: The answer is in the question: Ruby lacks proper constants :-)

Comment: The funny thing is if I *freeze* the `Fixnum` class so `**` cann't be redefined, Ruby's optimizer ignores this.

Comment: Again: the `freeze`ing happens at *runtime*. Figuring out at compile time whether or not the class was frozen is, again, equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. Plus, you could, at runtime, monkey-patch `Object#freeze` as well, so you have basically just restated the same question with a different method :-)

Comment: The reason why this works, say, in Scala or in C++ or similar, is because the Language Specification *guarantees* that certain operations *must* behave a certain way and *cannot* be redefined. That way, compiler writers can be *sure* that the optimization won't break anything. (Actually, both C++ and Scala even *require* that this optimization is performed in certain cases, IOW it's not *just* an optimization, it's actually a language feature.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's theoretically correct, however it can be about an agreement to rely on `Object#frozen?` return value.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for giving another answer, but I don't want to remove or edit my previous one because of the interesting discussion under it.

As Jörg W Mittag said, ruby has to calculate expression given to `while` each time because it is simply impossible to say it is constant. For an extreme example, I come up with following code:

```
class Fixnum
  alias :original_plus :+

  @@increment = 0
  def self.increase!
    @@increment = @@increment.original_plus 1
  end

  def +(other)
    (original_plus(other)).original_plus(@@increment)
  end 
end

while 1+1 < 5
  puts Fixnum.increase!
end
puts 'done' 

# 1 
# 2
# 3
# done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def fib1
  a, b = 0, 1
  while b < 9999**4000
    a, b = b, a+b
  end
  puts "\tdone !"
end


def fib2
  a, b = 0, 1
  value = 9999**4000
  while b < value
    a, b = b, a+b
  end
  puts "\tdone !"
end
```

There'll be no difference!

The reason is that in your first test ruby is calculating `9999**4000` inside the method you are calling while the second test is using constant which is calculated outside (before Benchmark is started) and hence your second result is shorter for '9999**4000' calculation time.

UPDATE: Well, there actually is a huge difference between those two tests and ruby calculates 9999**4000 in a no-time - see @JorgWMittag comments below.

I am not deleting this answer to keep the comments alive.

Comment: Point of the question is why mentioned Ruby implementations do not automatically store constant result for you (optimization), why do you need to write it manually.

Comment: @DavidUnric - It does. Problem is within your tests.

Comment: Because figuring out whether or not `Fixnum#**` is modified to do something else during each iteration of the loop is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: Or, to put it another way: because it *isn't* a constant expression.

Comment: @BroiSatse The question is about the fact that recalculating the `9999**4000` is unnecessary if the result is cached, as it doesn't change during the loop execution. Some languages/JITs will recognize that and optimize the loop. It'd be interesting to see results from JRuby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks, it does make sense. And for Ruby it would be extremely difficult to do additional checks if inside loop directly or indirectly `**` method gets modified.

Comment: I'd add equivalent Python code **is** optimized with CPython, although it also allows overloading of arithmetic operators.

Comment: Overloading is not the problem. The problem is that Ruby allows the redefinition of built-in operators (or in other words, the fact that there *are* no built-in operators). It is simply impossible to statically determine what the result of `1+1` is, because `Fixnum#+` may be redefined at runtime. I don't think Python allows redefining the meaning of `int.__add__` at runtime.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, it seems correct it deny to modify at runtime: `int.__add__=lambda n: n**2/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'`

Comment: Whoever is upvoting this, this answer has *completely* missed the point. It's not about producing code that solves a problem, it's about explaining why the problem exists in the first place.

Comment: @meager - I agree however it was not missed - i didn't try to fix the code, I noticed that first test is doing one more thing than the second one, and that difference could affect final result. Unfortunately I cannot downvote my own answer. :(